# How to separate and extract numerical values from 1 column in a dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe

I am new to working with data frames and R. I am looking for a way to manipulate and extract information from one of the columns. See below for an example data frame:

[image]

Column 3 "Info" contains AF, GF, and DT. I need the number from AF and the number after the comma in GF. Then I want to divide the number from GF by the number from AF to get a new variable XX which I would want to incorporate back into the DF as a new column. Maybe the visual below will help clarify what I need.

From A, I would take 20/10 =2, B would be 20/20 =1, C would be 7/10 = 0.7 etc. I want to generate a new column using these values called XX and add it to the original data frame:

[image]

I was approaching my issue more manually, like I said I am not familiar with R.

```
    library(dplyr)  
    library(tidyr)  
    library(stringr)  
    DF1 = data.frame(ID=c(A,B,C,D,E), TagNo=c(10,20,20,10,50),    Info=c(AF=10;GF=5,20;DT=10,AF=20;GF=4,20;DT=30,AF=10;GF=3,7;DT=40,AF=5;GF=2,15;DT=8,AF=2;GF=0,6;DT=10),Year=c(2022,2023,2023,2022,2022)  
    DF1_col3 = separate(DF1,c(1),into =c('AF', 'GF', 'DT'),sep=';')
```

Once I do this, it starts getting really messy. My original file has many more columns and milIions of rows. I appreciate any ideas.

Answer (score 4):

`strcapture` with regex capture groups and some basic vectorised operations for the final calculation:

```
DF1$XX <- with(strcapture("AF=(\\d+).+GF=.+,(\\d+)", 
                          DF1$Info, proto=list(x=1L,y=1L)), y/x)

#  ID TagNo                Info Year  XX
#1  A    10 AF=10;GF=5,20;DT=10 2022 2.0
#2  B    20 AF=20;GF=4,20;DT=30 2023 1.0
#3  C    20  AF=10;GF=3,7;DT=40 2023 0.7
#4  D    10   AF=5;GF=2,15;DT=8 2022 3.0
#5  E    50   AF=2;GF=0,6;DT=10 2022 3.0
```

Answer (score 3):

We can extract all numbers from `info` into a numeric vector we can subset with brackets, then do the calculations with elements #1 and #3. Must be a `rowwise()` operation

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df |>
    rowwise() |>
    mutate(xx = str_extract_all(Info,
                                '\\d+',
                                simplify = TRUE
                                ) |>
               as.numeric() |>
               {\(x) (x[3])/(x[1])}()
           ) |>
    ungroup()

# A tibble: 5 × 5
  ID    TagNo Info                 Year    xx
  <chr> <dbl> <chr>               <dbl> <dbl>
1 A        10 AF=10;GF=5,20;DT=10  2022   2  
2 B        20 AF=20;GF=4,20;DT=30  2023   1  
3 C        20 AF=10;GF=3,7;DT=40   2023   0.7
4 D        10 AF=5;GF=2,15;DT=8    2022   3  
5 E        50 AF=2;GF=0,6;DT=10    2022   3
```

Alternatively, we may extract the values into proper variables, which may facilitate other downstream analyses. I recommend using the new `tidyr::separate_wider_regex` for that, as in the example below. This should be faster in large datasets, because the `mutate()` operation is vectorized (much faster than `rowwise()`)

```
DF1 |>
    separate_wider_regex(cols = Info,
                         patterns = c('AF\\=',
                                      AF = '\\d+',
                                      ';',
                                      'GF\\=',
                                      GF = '\\d+',
                                      ',',
                                      other_number = '\\d+',
                                      ';',
                                      'DT\\=',
                                      DT = '\\d+'
                                      ),
                            
                         ) |>
    type.convert(as.is = TRUE) |>
    mutate(xx = other_number / AF)

# A tibble: 5 × 8
  ID    TagNo    AF    GF other_number    DT  Year    xx
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>        <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 A        10    10     5           20    10  2022   2  
2 B        20    20     4           20    30  2023   1  
3 C        20    10     3            7    40  2023   0.7
4 D        10     5     2           15     8  2022   3  
5 E        50     2     0            6    10  2022   3
```

data

```
structure(list(ID = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"), TagNo = c(10, 
20, 20, 10, 50), Info = c("AF=10;GF=5,20;DT=10", "AF=20;GF=4,20;DT=30", 
"AF=10;GF=3,7;DT=40", "AF=5;GF=2,15;DT=8", "AF=2;GF=0,6;DT=10"
), Year = c(2022, 2023, 2023, 2022, 2022)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))

  ID TagNo                Info Year
1  A    10 AF=10;GF=5,20;DT=10 2022
2  B    20 AF=20;GF=4,20;DT=30 2023
3  C    20  AF=10;GF=3,7;DT=40 2023
4  D    10   AF=5;GF=2,15;DT=8 2022
5  E    50   AF=2;GF=0,6;DT=10 2022
```

Comment: I get what you are doing, but for some reason RStudio doesn't recognize type_convert() function for me. Which library is this? I am already using dplyr, tidyr, and stringr

Comment: sorry, I forgot to tell `type_convert()` is from the `readr` package. We can also use the base R `type.convert()` too. Edited to use the base R version

Answer (score 2):

Also using `separate` and `str_extract` with regex:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
DF1 %>%
  separate(Info, into = c("AF", "GF", "DT"), sep = ";", convert = TRUE) %>% 
  mutate(AF = as.numeric(str_extract(AF, "\\d+")),
         GF = as.numeric(str_extract(GF, "(?<=,)\\d+")),
         XX = GF / AF)
```

```
  ID TagNo AF GF    DT Year  XX
1  A    10 10 20 DT=10 2022 2.0
2  B    20 20 20 DT=30 2023 1.0
3  C    20 10  7 DT=40 2023 0.7
4  D    10  5 15  DT=8 2022 3.0
5  E    50  2  6 DT=10 2022 3.0
```